# Error saving this JS in WSO2-Integration Studio

Tags: javascript, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-integration-studio

I use Integration Studio,
and I have always used inside my Xml files js script,

But this time I still get an error saving this inline JS, and I really can't understand the reason of this error.

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var elements = mc.getProperty('elementsFromJson');
         var payload = [];
         for(let i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++){
         var id= elements[i].id;
         var type= elements[i].type;
         var couple= {"id":id ,"type":type};
         print(couple);
         payload.push(couple);
         }
    var payloadFinale = {payload};
    print('result in JSON: ' + payloadFinale);
    var data= mc.setPayloadJSON(payloadFinale);]]></script>
```

So would be great your help in case you use Integration studio as me,
thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You have issues in the following lines.

```
for(let i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++){
```

Here change `let => var`

```
var payloadFinale = {payload};
```

The above syntax is wrong, not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Probably, you can remove the above line, when you do `mc.setPayloadJSON` it would be saved as a proper JSON.